# How to find Lepton Number?

Tags: standard-model, particle-physics, quarks, baryons, leptons

is a Standard Model particle with (u, d, b) quark content. What are the
electric charge, baryon number and lepton number of this particle? Is this the
only particle expected to exist with this quark content? Justify your answer

I know that the overall charge is 0, baryon number is 1. But what is the lepton number? ( The answer is 0) . Why is it 0? Why is it not the only expected particle with this quark content?

Comment: The leptons are the $e$, $\mu$, $\tau$, and the neutrinos.  How many leptons and antileptons are there in a particle made of $u$, $d$, $b$ quarks?

Comment: how do I know which particle do these quarks construct?

Comment: Maybe [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model), [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_baryons), [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_particles) and [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mesons) will help you

Comment: Take the lepton numbers of the u, d and b quarks and add them together and you get the lepton number of the particle(s) they make up. Re your last question, in particle physics different excited states of the same three quarks are regarded as different particles.